# PowerShell checkbox controls button function

Tags: forms, powershell, user-interface

This is my very first school project in PowerShell. Its going to be simple. Type path and press button to Get-Acl, which works, but I want to have an option for recurse. Which also works, but I have not been able to make a checkbox determine what function button has.. Specifically The checkboxstatechanged is what I need help with.

```
    function ChckBx_chkd {
     $table = Get-ChildItem  -directory -path $Textbox1.Text -recurse

    $Rtbx = @()
    foreach ($dir in $table)
    {
        
        $Access = (Get-Acl $dir.FullName).Access
        
        $Rtbx += $dir.PSPath
        $Rtbx += $Access | Format-Table | out-string

     }
     }

     function ChkcBx_unchkd { 
     $Rtbx.Text = (Get-Acl $Textbox1.Text).Access| Format-Table| Out-String
     }

      $Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    
      #Själva Formen

      $Form.Text = "ACL GUI"
    
      $Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Lucida Console",8)
        $Form.Font = $Font
    
      $Form.Width = 1000
      $Form.Height = 500

      $Rtbx = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
      $Rtbx.Location = '200, 100'
      $Rtbx.Width = 750
      $Rtbx.Font = $Font
      $Rtbx.Height = 300
      $Rtbx.Font
      
      $Form.Controls.Add($Rtbx)

      $Chkbx1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
      $Chkbx1.Location = '50, 150'
      $Chkbx1.Text = "undermappar"
      $Chkbx1.Checked = $true
      $Chkbx1.Add_CheckStateChanged({ 
               if($Chkbx1.checked) {
    $Btn1Click = ChckBx_chkd
     }
    else
    {
    $Btn1Click = ChkcBx_unchkd
     }
    
    })

      $Form.Controls.Add($Chkbx1)
    
      $Textbox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
      $Textbox1.Location = '50, 50'
      $Textbox1.Width = 700
      $Form.Controls.Add($Textbox1)

      $Btn1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
      $Btn1.Location = '50, 100'
      $Btn1.Text = "Get ACL"
      $Btn1.Font = 
      $Btn1.Width = 100
      $Btn1.Add_Click($Btn1Click) 

      $Form.Controls.Add($Btn1)

      $Form.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I have to say that with the code formatted as it is, it makes it very hard to see where the functions and loops start and end.  Pick a style a stick with it.
2. Your function names are spelt oddly which is confusing `ChckBx_unchkd` and `ChkcBx_chkd` - why reverse `ck` in the prefix?
3. Your `ChkcBx_chkd` code doesn't appear to work - you're redefining the variable `$Rtbx` as an array where you want to set the `.Text` property.
4. You have no default value set so `$Btn1Click` is undefined until you change the checkbox state at least once.
5. Your assignment of `$Btn1Click = ChckBx_chkd` actually calls that function at that point where you appear be using it as a reference which you then call later.  You should do `$Btn1Click = "ChckBx_chkd"` (i.e. a string name of the function) then later use `Invoke-Expression $Btn1Click`
6. The scope of your variables is not the same.  Changing `$Btn1Click` does not affect the value.  `Write-Host` is your friend - print the variables out to help you debug what values they have.  I've used `Get-Variable`/`Set-Variable` so I can use the variables in the `global` scope.

Revised code

```
function ChckBx_chkd {
    Write-Host "ChckBx_chkd called"
    $table = Get-ChildItem -directory -path $Textbox1.Text -recurse
    $Rtbx.Text = ""
    foreach ($dir in $table) {
        $Access = (Get-Acl $dir.FullName).Access
        $Rtbx.Text += $dir.PSPath
        $Rtbx.Text += $Access | Format-Table | out-string
    }
}

function ChkcBx_unchkd { 
    Write-Host "ChkcBx_unchkd called"
    $Rtbx.Text = (Get-Acl $Textbox1.Text).Access | Format-Table| Out-String
}

Set-Variable -Name Btn1Click -Value "ChckBx_chkd" -Scope Global

$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Lucida Console",8)

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = "ACL GUI"
$Form.Font = $Font
$Form.Width = 1000
$Form.Height = 500

$Rtbx = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$Rtbx.Location = '200, 100'
$Rtbx.Width = 750
$Rtbx.Font = $Font
$Rtbx.Height = 300
$Rtbx.Font
$Form.Controls.Add($Rtbx)

$Chkbx1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$Chkbx1.Location = '50, 150'
$Chkbx1.Text = "undermappar"
$Chkbx1.Checked = $true
$Chkbx1.Add_CheckStateChanged({ 
    Write-Host $Chkbx1.checked $(Get-Variable -Name Btn1Click -Scope Global).Value
    if ($Chkbx1.checked) {
        Set-Variable -Name Btn1Click -Value "ChckBx_chkd" -Scope Global
    } else {
        Set-Variable -Name Btn1Click -Value "ChkcBx_unchkd" -Scope Global
    }
    Write-Host $Chkbx1.checked $(Get-Variable -Name Btn1Click -Scope Global).Value
})
$Form.Controls.Add($Chkbx1)

$Textbox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Textbox1.Location = '50, 50'
$Textbox1.Width = 700
$Form.Controls.Add($Textbox1)

$Btn1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Btn1.Location = '50, 100'
$Btn1.Text = "Get ACL"
$Btn1.Font = 
$Btn1.Width = 100
$Btn1.Add_Click({Invoke-Expression $(Get-Variable -Name Btn1Click -Scope Global).Value})

$Form.Controls.Add($Btn1)

$Form.ShowDialog()
```